# Having incrementing problems in Arduino code

Tags: arduino, sensors

Basically I am reading raw values from an accelerometer (i.e these values change in response to gravity and acceleration). 
I have set a range of values for the raw values(i.e from **-100** to **100** instead):

```
x = map(ax, -2048, 2048, -100, 100 );
```

now im trying to increment "count" x greater than 50:

```
if (x>50) {
    count++;
  }
```

main example code here:

```
void loop(){
x = map(ax, -2048, 2048, -100, 100 );
if (x>50) {
        count++;
      }
}
```

but when I compile the code, x becomes greater than 50 and the count just keeps incrementing and what I want it to do is count 'one by one' only when the value becomes greater than 50 seen as the values change as accelerometer moves?

Comment: Could yo explain it a bit better ? the cuestion isn't clear at all.
What do you mean with 'one by one' ?

Comment: I'm guessing you want to do the map and if() only if there is new data from the accelerometer. Can you post more of your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to count how many times you measure a value over 50. If you check the condition in every `loop()` iteration, then you will get how many time (measured in *loops*) the value is over 50.

You need something like this

```
boolean checked = false;

void loop(){
x = map(ax, -2048, 2048, -100, 100 );
if (x > 50 && !checked) {
    count++;
    checked = true;
    }
if (x < 50 && checked) {
    checked = false;
    }
}
```